# Having a weird behavior in my application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I navigate into a second screen in my React Native Application, and below is the constructor of the second screen:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const navParams = props.navigation.state.params;

    if(navParams !== undefined && navParams.eventId) {
        let MyStr = "Inside IF";
    } 
    else 
    {
        let MyStr = "Inside ELSE";             
    }
}
```

`navParams` is not *undefined* (See Watch below), also `eventId` is not null (See Watch below). Yet, the `else` statement is being executed instead of the `if`.

What would be the issue that is causing this weird behavior?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`eventId` is `0` which mean this would fail `(navParams !== undefined && navParams.eventId)`.

You would need more something like

`(navParams !== undefined && navParams.eventId !== undefined)`

or

`(navParams !== undefined && navParams.eventId > -1)`.

If the value is `0` it will evaluate as `false` basically.

Comment: Interesting! Welcome to JS?

Comment: @KyleKhalaf Yes JS has few hidden secrets like that which can trick new users